# how to change minimum windows target version in cordova windows 10 project?

Tags: cordova, uwp

I could not change cordova windows minimum target version, I had tried to change it in CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj but it's overwritten after every build,

```
    <TargetPlatformIdentifier>UAP</TargetPlatformIdentifier>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.10240.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <MinimumVisualStudioVersion>14.0</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
    <UapDefaultAssetScale>100</UapDefaultAssetScale>
```

please help...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to change minimum windows target version in cordova windows 10 project?

If you want to modify uwp target version, please refer this [document](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html). And add the following lines to config.xml file.

```
 <preference name="uap-target-min-version" value="10.0.16299.0" /> 
 <preference name="Windows.Universal-MinVersion" value="10.0.16299.0" />
```

Comment: Thank you for you comment, I have changed the windows target minimum version to 16299 and it works but when I run application,  the version 16299 does not work with windows runtime ( I am using a c# winmd file)  but when I change it to 15063 then it works . What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @AvishekNath what's c# winmd file, Please  share a sample project for us, you could upload project to github and share the link.

Comment: I am using a windows runtime project , for uwp application i am using cordova and refering this winrt project from a cordova plugin. You can check this link , https://github.com/jimcloudman/winjs-error-for-testing

Comment: @AvishekNath, I have update the reply please check. The previous way does not work. it will be overwritten after build.

Comment: Guys, I am also having a similar issue where the Cordova win10 app is not able to call Windows Runtime Component. It throws an unknown runtime error. Any idea how to solve this? Thanks